# How to Look a tab HIddenmidpoint Column A and if it matches Column M on Step 2 tab then output what is on Column B on the hiddenmidpoint Tab

Tags: excel

I am trying to take Excel and look to see if what is in Column M on the Step 2 Tab matches what is in Column A of the Hidden Pointpoint Tab.  If it DOES match then output what is in Column B of the Hidden Midpoint Tab.

I am very new to this level of excel.

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP for that

Comment: I have never used a Vlookup in excel, I am very new to this.. I will google it and give it a shot